# Categorical attribute splitting for Classification and Regression Tree (CART)

Tags: machine-learning, classification, decision-tree

I know we can split numerical attributes multiple times in different levels for Classification and Regression Tree (CART) which is a binary tree. How about categorical attributes? Can we split multiple times or only one time? if not, what is the reason?

Answer (score 1):

If the categorical predictors have more than 2 categories; you can split it again as you do in case of a numerical variable.

For Example;

If one of the predictors is **'Marital Status' with 3 categories**: 'Married', 'Unmarried' and 'Divorced'.

You can have one binary split like **'Unmarried' Vs 'Others'** where the latter group consists of the observations of both the groups 'Married' and 'Divorced'.

Further, if required at some stage, you can split 'Other' group into two categories **'Married' and 'Divorced'**.

Based on some splitting rule, you can extend this idea for more than 3 categories too.

Answer (score 0):

Binary trees are binary.

If you do a multi-way split, it no longer is binary, and finding the optimum split becomes more expensive than you would like, while the overall capabilities don't change compared to using multiple levels.